# Alfa wifi dongle not working ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, usb

My alfa awus036ac usb dongle is not even showing its powered up when i plug it into my computer while running ubuntu 20.04, however it runs on my windows and on my parrot OS's
please help me with the correct process to get it running, so I may use kali on virtualbox for packet injection and monitor mode. ??

Comment: Is the dongle listed in the output if you run the command 'lsusb'? Have you tried installing the drivers ([these instructions for Kali might also work in Ubuntu](https://exitcode0.net/awus036ac-rt8812au-driver-setup-in-kali-linux/))?

Comment: this is the response to lsusb command that relates to my alfa... so YES, it does read the device is present ... I might add, there are only 3 USB ports, im using an ASUS X751M; and plugged in are my USB wireless mouse / my USB adapter cord for the SSD disk im using / and then finally my alfa USB wifi adapter...
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:b722 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n blah blah blah.......
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac 2T2R DB WLAN Adapter

Comment: also, the link that you refer to does not work so far, on ubuntu for me.. i am currently trying it with kali in my Virtualbox, however that stil does not solve the problem ?